# Transparency using HLSL in XNA

Tags: xna, c#, hlsl, kinect

I currently working on Depth Data on Kinect SDK v1.8 on XNA and I wanna show an Image Inside the Depth view of Human body. the image below is just an example of what I wanna do :

http://static.gamespot.com/uploads/original/1535/15354745/2429785-screen4.jpg

for Depth View, this is what I've done :

```
void kinectSensor_DepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (DepthImageFrame depthImageFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
    {
        if (depthImageFrame != null)
        {
            short[] pixelsFromFrame = new short[depthImageFrame.PixelDataLength];

            depthImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelsFromFrame);
            byte[] convertedPixels = ConvertDepthFrame(pixelsFromFrame, ((KinectSensor)sender).DepthStream, 640 * 480 * 4);

            Color[] color = new Color[depthImageFrame.Height * depthImageFrame.Width];
            kinectRGBVideo = new Texture2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, depthImageFrame.Width, depthImageFrame.Height);

            // Set convertedPixels from the DepthImageFrame to a the datasource for our Texture2D
            kinectRGBVideo.SetData<byte>(convertedPixels);
        }
    }
}


// Converts a 16-bit grayscale depth frame which includes player indexes into a 32-bit frame
// that displays different players in different colors
private byte[] ConvertDepthFrame(short[] depthFrame, DepthImageStream depthStream, int depthFrame32Length)
{
    int tooNearDepth = depthStream.TooNearDepth;
    int tooFarDepth = depthStream.TooFarDepth;
    int unknownDepth = depthStream.UnknownDepth;
    byte[] depthFrame32 = new byte[depthFrame32Length];

    for (int i16 = 0, i32 = 0; i16 < depthFrame.Length && i32 < depthFrame32.Length; i16++, i32 += 4)
    {
        int player = depthFrame[i16] & DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmask;
        int realDepth = depthFrame[i16] >> DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmaskWidth;

        // transform 13-bit depth information into an 8-bit intensity appropriate
        // for display (we disregard information in most significant bit)
        byte intensity = (byte)(~(realDepth >> 4));

        if (player == 0 && realDepth == 0)
        {
            // white 
            depthFrame32[i32 + RedIndex] = 255;
            depthFrame32[i32 + GreenIndex] = 255;
            depthFrame32[i32 + BlueIndex] = 255;
        }
        else if (player == 0 && realDepth == tooFarDepth)
        {
            // dark purple
            depthFrame32[i32 + RedIndex] = 66;
            depthFrame32[i32 + GreenIndex] = 0;
            depthFrame32[i32 + BlueIndex] = 66;
        }
        else if (player == 0 && realDepth == unknownDepth)
        {
            // dark brown
            depthFrame32[i32 + RedIndex] = 66;
            depthFrame32[i32 + GreenIndex] = 66;
            depthFrame32[i32 + BlueIndex] = 33;
        }
        else
        {
            // tint the intensity by dividing by per-player values
            depthFrame32[i32 + RedIndex] = (byte)(intensity >> IntensityShiftByPlayerR[player]);
            depthFrame32[i32 + GreenIndex] = (byte)(intensity >> IntensityShiftByPlayerG[player]);
            depthFrame32[i32 + BlueIndex] = (byte)(intensity >> IntensityShiftByPlayerB[player]);
        }
    }

    return depthFrame32;
}
```

I'm not sure how I can get the Object inside the Depth View of the body.
Update : I found out I can use HLSL to achieve this for a 3D model :

```
float4x4 World;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;
float4x4 WorldInverseTranspose;

float4 AmbientColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
float AmbientIntensity = 0.1;

float3 DiffuseLightDirection = float3(1, 0, 0);
float4 DiffuseColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
float DiffuseIntensity = 1.0;

float Shininess = 200;
float4 SpecularColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
float SpecularIntensity = 1;
float3 ViewVector = float3(1, 0, 0);

float Transparency = 0.5;

texture ModelTexture;
sampler2D textureSampler = sampler_state {
    Texture = (ModelTexture);
    MinFilter = Linear;
    MagFilter = Linear;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float4 Normal : NORMAL0;
    float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
    float3 Normal : TEXCOORD0;
    float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD1;
};

VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
        float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
        output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);

    float4 normal = normalize(mul(input.Normal, WorldInverseTranspose));
        float lightIntensity = dot(normal, DiffuseLightDirection);
    output.Color = saturate(DiffuseColor * DiffuseIntensity * lightIntensity);

    output.Normal = normal;

    output.TextureCoordinate = input.TextureCoordinate;
    return output;
}

float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
    float3 light = normalize(DiffuseLightDirection);
    float3 normal = normalize(input.Normal);
    float3 r = normalize(2 * dot(light, normal) * normal - light);
    float3 v = normalize(mul(normalize(ViewVector), World));
    float dotProduct = dot(r, v);

    float4 specular = SpecularIntensity * SpecularColor * max(pow(dotProduct, Shininess), 0) * length(input.Color);

        float4 textureColor = tex2D(textureSampler, input.TextureCoordinate);
        textureColor.a = 1;

    float4 color = saturate(textureColor * (input.Color) + AmbientColor * AmbientIntensity + specular);
        color.a = Transparency;
    return color;
}

technique Textured
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        AlphaBlendEnable = TRUE;
        DestBlend = INVSRCALPHA;
        SrcBlend = SRCALPHA;
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VertexShaderFunction();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

and this is my Draw Code in Game1 Class:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        DrawModelWithEffect(model, world, view, projection);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    private void DrawModelWithEffect(Model model, Matrix world, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
    {
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (ModelMeshPart part in mesh.MeshParts)
            {
                part.Effect = effect;
                effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(world * mesh.ParentBone.Transform);
                effect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(view);
                effect.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(projection);
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

My problem is that I want to use this same idea to create a transparency between two 2D Images.

Is there something like this out there for 2D? If so where can I find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote HLSL code for transparency and then I will transparent one image inside the body and another image used for my foreground :

```
sampler stream : register(s0);
sampler back : register(s1);
sampler character : register(s2);



float4 DepthToRGB(float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
// We can't easily sample non-normalized data,
// Texture is a short packed stuffed into a BGRA4444 (4 bit per component normalized)
// It's not really BGRA4444 which is why we have to reverse the normalization here
float4 color = tex2D(stream, texCoord);
float4 backColor =  tex2D(back, texCoord);
float4 characterColor = tex2D(character, texCoord);

// convert from [0,1] to [0,15]
color *= 15.01f;

// unpack the individual components into a single int
int4 iColor = (int4)color;
int depthV = iColor.w * 4096 + iColor.x * 256 + iColor.y * 16 + iColor.z;

// player mask is in the lower 8 bits
int playerId = depthV % 8;

if(playerId == 0)
{
    //Not yet recognized
    return backColor * float4(1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0);
}
else
{
    return backColor * characterColor;
}
}

technique KinectDepth
{
pass KinectDepth
{
    PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 DepthToRGB();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that in XNA (and all other 3D libraries), 2D *is* 3D! In XNA, sprites are just 3D planes drawn to the screen. Any shader you use in 3D will work just as well with the spritebatch. Spritebatch.Begin() has a parameter for the shader to pass in.

If I'm following you, you want to use the depth image to blend between two images. Here's what I would do:

- Render the entire scene to a RenderTarget2D
- Draw a quad to the screen using the RenderTarget2D as a texture.
- In a custom HLSL shader, sample the depth image from the Kinect to determine whether to blend between the previous texture or some other texture.

Comment: Thanks for your guides, but would you please help me in the code ? I totally confused :-(